# Confusion with process of creation an object when we use new keyword

Tags: javascript

I was learning JS and slightly confused with what happens behind the scenes with creation an object with new keyword. As I found out, three things basically happen when we use new keyword:

> 1. A new empty object is created and assigned to this.
> 2. The function body executes. Usually it modifies this, adds new properties to it.
> 3. The value of this is returned.

Look, in the step two when function body executes, Does it run all of the body code and puts all functions and properties having "this" into object which was created in step 1? I mean, what is the reason of running the function body in step 2. Here is the sample code:

```js
function PageState(){
  let currentState = new homeState();

  this.change = function(state){
    currentState=state;
  }
}

const page = new PageState();

function homeState(){
  document.querySelector('.div').style.width = "100px";
}
```

Comment: Post some code [mcve]

Comment: The constructor code **initializes** the new object. It may do nothing, or it may do many things; it all depends on the application.

Comment: @zer00ne, posted

Comment: @zer00ne, just one question, Does it run all of the body code and puts all functions and properties having "this" (for example: this.car="BMW" and this.drive=function(){}) into object which was created in step 1? So, the reason of running function body is to find properties and functions assigned to "this" and put  them into object that was created in step 1. Is that correct? Hope it is clear

Comment: Yes, it runs all the code until *return* or the last statement, whichever comes first. The code is not particularly enlightening. *currentState* initially references a new *homeState* instance, but setting it through the *change* method replaces that reference with a new value and doesn't return anything. Nor is there any way to read the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code snippet, step 1 happens automatically, then I assign some members (properties or methods) to `this` which is step 2, then step 3, `this` is returned.

Calling `const object1 = new MyObject()` means create an object with `greeting` set to 'Hi', `name` set to 'Tim', and `getMessage` set to a function that returns the concatenated message; then assign that object to object1.

You can create a new instance of MyObject by calling `const object2 = new MyObject();` and that time the function runs, there is a new `this`.

You can modify your objects without affecting the original function/object used to create the others.

```js
function MyObject() {
  this.greeting = 'Hi';
  this.name = 'Tim';
  this.getMessage = function() {
    return this.greeting + ' ' + this.name + '!';
  }
}

const object1 = new MyObject();
const object2 = new MyObject();
object2.greeting = 'Yo';
object2.name = 'Sam';
const object3 = new MyObject();

console.log( object1.getMessage() );
console.log( object2.getMessage() );
console.log( object3.getMessage() );
```

Comment: thank you for your kind answer, can I imagine it like this the reason for running function body in step 2 is to find all properties and functions assigned to "this"(for example: this.car="BMW" and this.drive=function(){}) and put them into function created in step 1. Right?

Comment: Yup. Think of it as the `object` created in step one instead of the function created in step one